# Youtube API insert video returns INVALID_ARGUMENT

Tags: curl, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to use the youtube api to allow a user to upload a video from a website I'm making.

This is the request I'm sending (almost exactly the same as the example from the documentation, for now):

```bash
curl --request POST 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2Cstatus&key=[MY-API-KEY]' \
  -H 'authorization: Bearer [THE-USERS-ACCESS-TOKEN]' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'origin: http://localhost:1234' \
  --data-raw '{"snippet":{"categoryId":"22","description":"Description of uploaded video.","title":"Test video upload."},"status":{"privacyStatus":"private"}}' \
  --compressed
```

The response is an error that lacks a bit of details:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I believe my api key and credentials are OK because I've tested them with other methods (that require user credentials), and they work fine.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) is not super clear about where to put the actual video file's bytes. I'm sort of expecting the method to return a resumable upload url, but the doc says nothing about that.
It states that Accepted Media MIME types are **video/*** and **application/octet-stream**, but also that you should provide a video resource in the request body, and all examples show a json body and content-type...

How is this method supposed to work ?

Comment: try --data not --data-raw

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't help

Comment: Sorry i cant help more i have never seen anyone try to do an upload to the api using curl it will be interesting to see if you get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to upload a video file with the resumable upload using YouTube API.
- You want to achieve this using the curl command.

In this case, how about the following sample curl command?

In order to upload a video file to YouTube with the resumable upload using YouTube API, the following 2 processes are required to be done.

#### 1. Retrieve the location URL.

As the 1st step, the location URL for uploading the video data is retrieved.

```bash
curl -X POST -i "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet%2Cstatus" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ### Your access token ###" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" \
  -d "{\"snippet\":{\"categoryId\":\"22\",\"description\":\"Description of uploaded video.\",\"title\":\"Test video upload.\"},\"status\":{\"privacyStatus\":\"private\"}}"
```

- The file metadata is from your showing curl command.
- Please retrieve `location: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet%2Cstatus&upload_id=###` from the response header. The video data is uploaded using this URL.

#### 2. Upload video data.

As the 2nd step, the video data is uploaded using the retrieved location URL.

Please replace `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet%2Cstatus&upload_id=###` with your URL. And, please modify the filename.

```bash
curl -X PUT -i 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet%2Cstatus&upload_id=###' \
-F "file=@sample.mp4;type=video/mp4"
```

- In this case, the video data is uploaded with a single chunk. If you want to use multiple chunks, please read the official document. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol)

#### Note:

- As a simple test, I would like to recommend using a small video file.
- When I tested the above curl commands, I confirmed that the video file could be uploaded to YouTube. If an error occurs, please confirm your access token, metadata, your video file, and so on, again.
- If you want to upload the video file using `multipart/form-data`, you can also the following sample curl command.

  ```bash
  curl -X POST -i 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=multipart&part=snippet%2Cstatus' \
    -H 'authorization: Bearer ### Your access token ###' \
    -F "metadata={\"snippet\":{\"categoryId\":\"22\",\"description\":\"Description of uploaded video.\",\"title\":\"Test video upload.\"},\"status\":{\"privacyStatus\":\"private\"}};type=application/json;charset=UTF-8" \
    -F "file=@sample.mp4;type=video/mp4"
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Resumable Uploads](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol)

Comment: This looks super promising! I'll give it a try.
I don't understand how I should have figured this out from the documentation (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert): the word 'resumable' is nowhere to be found, and there is no mention of the PUT method either... Am I being dumb or is the documentation a bit lacking here ?

Comment: @bastien girschig Thank you for replying. About `the word 'resumable' is nowhere to be found, and there is no mention of the PUT method either`, I agree with your comment. In my case, I have used the resumable upload with Drive API. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads#resumable) I confirmed that when I tested this process on YouTube, the basic resumable upload process is the same between Drive API and YouTube API. I think that this information was useful for me. But, about the resumable upload with YouTube API, I will tell to Google side.

Comment: I've used resumable uploads with cloud storage before, but the generic error message and poor documentation got me stuck. And thanks to your comment, I realized I was actually not hitting the correct endpoint: most API methods use this url pattern "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/ **whatever**" but to upload I need to use "https://www.googleapis.com/ **upload** /youtube/v3/videos"

Comment: @bastien girschig Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot understand your current issue for my proposed answer. When I tested my proposed curl command, the video file can be uploaded to YouTube. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the detail of your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. I deeply apologize that when I tested my answer, no error occurs.

Comment: Sorry. I was not clear. Your answer was perfectly fine, I was just giving more details about what was wrong with my code in the first place.

Comment: @bastien girschig Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About the endpoint, I agree with your comment. In the case of `www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos`, `www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable` can be seen in the official document of the resumable upload. But, `www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=multipart` cannot be found. In this case, I thought that knowledge about Drive API might be required to be used.